# Parse HTML using Xpath?

Tags: html, parsing, html-agility-pack

I want to help my problem is: I get the data but the data obtained in duplicate. Thank you.
**HTML**

```
<div id="items" style="width: 940px; height: 2176px; position: relative;">
        <div class="item masonry-brick" style="top: 0px; right: 0px; position: absolute;">
        <div class="picture">
            <a title="bikini" class="image" href="...-bikini.html">
                <img alt="bikini" src="...13508.jpg">
            </a>
            <div class="item-content">
                <h2><a href="...bikini.html">bikini</a></h2>
                <div class="item_social">
                    <ul>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span>6</span></li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i><span>0</span></li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-comments"></i><span>0</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="author-post">
                    <a class="author" href="....nuong" rel="nofollow">
                        <img class="author_avatar" alt="nương" src="....ae3c3d8a6a.png">

                        <span class="author_name">nương</span>
                        <ul class="author_item">
                            <li><span>13 giờ trước </span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
//..... more item masonry-brick
 </div>
```

My code C# parsing "but the data obtained in duplicate image and text!",but full item number.

```
HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlPage);
List<Data> datas = new List<Data>();
foreach (var div in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[starts-with(@class, 'item')]"))

{
    Data newdata = new Data();
    newdata.Imgsrc = div.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='picture']//img").Attributes["src"].Value;
    newdata.Title = div.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='item-content']//h2").InnerText.Trim();
    newdata.Summary = div.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='author-post']//span").InnerText.Trim();
    datas.Add(newdata);
}
lstDatas.ItemsSource = datas;
```

Thanks you!
[image: Error!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add period/dot (`.`) at the beginning of your XPath to indicate that the XPath searching scope is local within current `div` context :

```
foreach (var div in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[starts-with(@class, 'item')]"))
{
    Data newdata = new Data();
    newdata.Imgsrc = div.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='picture']//img").Attributes["src"].Value;
    newdata.Title = div.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='item-content']//h2").InnerText.Trim();
    newdata.Summary = div.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='author-post']//span").InnerText.Trim();
    datas.Add(newdata);
}
```

Otherwise, the XPath will search within entire `HtmlDocument` and return the first matched node again and again in every iteration, that's why you got those duplicates.